# Strange changing background color in VIM solarized

Tags: vim, terminal, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting

I don't know exactly how to describe this issue, but when using solarized colorscheme theme in terminal vim, I'm noticing that when I edit some text various ends of lines (not "line-endings" but from the last letter to the end of the buffer) will be somewhat highlighted. Once I move for example using `<C-e>`, or `<C-y>`, the weird highlighting fixes itself and becomes the background color.

Ideally I'd like to fix this and just have my background always be the background-color. But any insight as to what's going on/ being highlighted would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**after having just edited text**
[image: with weird highlighting]
**after pressing `<C-e>`**
[image]

Comment: Screenshots with opaque background would be better. What is your `$TERM`? What is your terminal emulator?

Comment: I can reupload some screenshots. I'm using normal Mac OSX terminal and my $TERM is `xterm-256color` thanks

Comment: Are you running through any program like `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: yes! I'm using screen.. do you think that has something to do with it?

Comment: try adding `term screen-256color` to your `.screenrc`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As explained here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html), disable **Background Color Erase** (BCE) by clearing the `t_ut` terminal option (run `:set t_ut=` in Vim and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the terminal's display) so that color schemes work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.